# item.systemupdate() working only for share point online and not for on premise csom

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Tried to use item.systemupdate() SharePoint 2013 and 2016 environment using csom. However it throws exception"system update" method cannot be found.

The same thing is working for SharePoint online

Is it the limitation that it will work only for online SharePoint and not for on-prem csom

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your best option for on-premises solutions is the [ListItem.ValidateUpdateListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771256.aspx) method. It can update a list item without creating a new version. But it will update the last modified by user and the last modified timestamp unless you explicitly set those fields in your request.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll that you are using. If possible get the latest version from NuGet and then check.

This seems to be related to the dll.

Comment: Item.systemupdate() from Microsoft.client.dll works only for online and not for on-prem as the nuget package itself is Microsoft.Online.Sharepoint... Need to find a way to use the alternative for Item.Systemupdate in on-prem csom also

Comment: Hi @nina, you can check this [link from Office Dev Center](https://dev.office.com/blogs/using-correct-csom-version-for-sharepoint-customizations) which explains the usage of different CSOM dlls. You will need to use different assemblies. For SharePoint 2013 the latest one is version 15.0.4711.1000. However, I have successfully used [SharePoint 2013 client components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585) with both SharePoint 2010 and Office 365 SP Online environments.